# Use headers from one dataframe to find the row indexes from a second

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use a reference table to take action based on the headers of a file I am importing into a dataframe.

```
print(df_reference_table)
file_type source          col_name1       col_name2      col_name3   ...                    
Status    G081            TAIL            MDS            BASE        ...
          LIMS-EV         Serial Number   Mission Design Location    ...
          IMDS            ACFT            Designator     CMD         ...

print(df_import_table.columns.values)
['TAIL' 'MDS' 'BASE']

cols_in = df_import_table.columns.value
```

I'm looking for something that will return [Status, G081], the script would add/delete/rename columns as needed so they match.  My source documents have different numbers of columns and I have no control over the format/names/length before it gets to me.

I've tried the following:

```
In:
t = df_import_table.columns.values
df_reference_table.loc[t]

Out: 
KeyError:['TAIL' 'MDS' 'BASE'] not in index

In: 
l = list(df_import_table.columns.values)
df_reference_table.loc[l]

Out: 
KeyError:['TAIL' 'MDS' 'BASE'] not in index

In:
t = df_import_table.columns.values
df_reference_table.index[df_reference_table.columns == t].tolist()

Out:
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

Basically, I want to do the reverse of -

```
df_format.loc['Status','G081'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean mask:

```
# Set 'file_type' and 'source' as index if it's not already the case
df_reference_table = df_reference_table.set_index(['file_type', 'source'])

cols = df_import_table.columns.tolist())
mask = df_reference_table.eq(cols).any(axis=1)

print(df_reference_table[mask].index.to_flat_index()[0])

# Output:
('Status', 'G081')
```

Comment: I had to change 
`mask = df_reference_table.eq(cols).all(axis=1)` to
`mask = df_reference_table.eq(cols).any(axis=1)` in order to overcome each of my tables having different numbers of columns, but otherwise worked

Comment: I updated my answer according your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Also had to add 
`nan = np.nan`
`cols_f = df_referemce_table.columns.tolist()`
`for n in range(len(cols), len(cols_f)): cols_in.append(nan)`